# Anuglar 6 Route From DataBase

Tags: angular6

Iam working on angular 6 application with default routing configuration ,
my question is how I can load route from database after user login this is how my route is now .

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "dashboard",
    pathMatch: "full"
  },

  {
    path: "services",
    data: { breadcrumb: "Services" },
    component: ServicesComponent,

  }]
```

and the api return the following results

```
{Path: "/Services", Component: "ServicesComponent"}
{Path: "/Dashboard", Component: "DashboardComponent"}
```

so how i can overwrite the route with new values

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically add routes to your `Router` instance whenever and wherever you want.

You need to access routes array and add a new one, like this:

```
this.router.config.unshift({path: 'myNewRoute', component: ProductListComponent});
```

**Decorator metadata solution**:

In your case you need to access `Module` metadata, more precisely `Decorator`'s declarations to search for the component you need. You can check that component's name match with the one received by DB.

```
let compName = 'ProductListComponent';
let comp: Type<any> = (<any>AppModule).__annotations__[0].declarations.find(comp => {
  return comp.name === compName;
});

this.router.config.unshift({path: 'myNewRoute', component: comp});
```

Obviously feel free to add integrity checks.

**Mapping solution**

You could more simply make a mapping of db string and component like this:

```
let mapping = {
  'myNewRoute': ProductListComponent,
   ...
}
```

Then unshift new route as follows:

```
this.router.config.unshift({path: 'myNewRoute', component: mapping['myNewRoute']});
```

Comment: thanks , but here you have componet name as type not string and what Ineed is to generate route not add item

Comment: i can't understand what you mean with "generate route". can you add all routes at the beginning and manage auth with AuthGuard? Or you could add all routes and then add some redirect so you can work with string

Comment: if the combinations of dinamyc routes is not very large you could define an interface between db and angular, for example based on user's roles

Comment: the scenario is after user login i get all menu related to user then i want to push them to route  so i created new component navcomponent on ngOnInt how to access route and convert string component name to object of component

Comment: thanks for your help, I only have one issue when trying to add app module to component i got warning
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\app-nav\app-nav.component.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app-nav\app-nav.component.ts

Comment: i think you can't solve that thing. But you can solve making a manual mapping from db string and types, i'm updating my answer